# Variable in loop on Python don't change

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't understand why in loop variable don't change, but I explicitly try it. So here is my code:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=["a","b","c"]
d=[a,b]
for i in d:
    for a in i:
         a*2
         print(a)
```

And when I run I see :

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

Instead expected:

```
2
4
6
aa
bb
cc
```

Comment: you should print `2 * a` not a

Comment: You are not assigning the new value to any variable. Replace `a*2` by `a=a*2`.

Comment: The line `a*2` gets "lost", it doesn't change the value of `a`. To do that you'd need to either reassign `a` its new value by doing `a = a * 2` or just print the desired value by doing `print a * 2`. Also, you are using the variable `a` for both the array and the inner variable in the second loop. Avoid this at all costs.

Comment: by the way I don't understand why people are downvoting this. Sure, it's an absolutely basic question, but for a person who is clearly completely new to programming, I'd say it's a totally legit question.

Comment: Rather than being a duplicate (the other question is about an entirely different confusion), this should have been closed as a typo. The expected behaviour makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the `a` when iterating `i`, you must assign the value to the variable.

so instead of

```
for a in i:
    a*2
    print(a)
```

try

```
for a in i:
    a = a*2
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not assigning value to the variable. It will change if you do a = a*2, instead of just a*2. Try this in python shell:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=["a","b","c"]
>>> d=[a,b]
>>> for i in d:
...     for a in i:
...         a=a*2
...         print(a)
... 
2
4
6
aa
bb
cc
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=["a","b","c"]
d=[a,b]
for i in d:
    for a in i:
         a=a*2 # change this line like that
         print(a)
```